# SSRS returned data type not valid for the aggregate function

Tags: reporting-services

I am making a SSRS, when executing the query

```
SELECT Brand.[KeyOffer],
   COALESCE(SUM([Key Offer].Revenue),0) as Revenue
FROM [Brand Key Offer] Brand
LEFT JOIN [Key Offer] ON Brand.Keyoffer = [Key Offer].[Key Offer] AND [Key Offer].[Date] = '7/05/2017'
WHERE Brand.[Brand] = 'SMART'
GROUP BY [Brand].[KeyOffer]
ORDER BY [Revenue] DESC
```

But when I preview the reprot, I get this warning message.

```
Warning     [rsAggregateOfInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox21.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function with an expression that returned a data type not valid for the aggregate function.       c:\users\t-aordiz\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TelemarketingRS\TelemarketingRS\Telemarketing Revenue.rdl   0
```

Ive been to a lot of topics but cant seem to find a way to solve this problem.

Comment: I am not sure this has to do with your query.  Does your query run in SSMS?  I think it might have more to do with something inside textbox21.  Does that textbox have an expression?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The same happened to me when I tried to change an output's datatype from datetime to varchar.

Try to delete the file **YourReportFile.rdl.data** and preview again. It worked for me in VS2015.

Comment: Thanks - deleting the *.rdl.data file fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is being caused by the call to `SUM()`, possibly because you are feeding it a non numeric type.  To test this, you could try casting `[Key Offer].Revenue` to decimal:

```
SELECT
    Brand.[KeyOffer],
    COALESCE(SUM(CAST([Key Offer].Revenue AS DECIMAL(10, 2))),0) AS Revenue
FROM [Brand Key Offer] Brand
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conversion in your expression to the appopriate type like below

```
= CDec(Fields!Revenue.value)
```

Also try the following SQL alternatives

```
COALESCE(SUM([Key Offer].Revenue),0.00)
```

or

```
CAST(COALESCE(SUM([Key Offer].Revenue),0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

(it's a little different from what Tim suggested)